# Нужно удалить в каждой строке кусок числа

Tags: c++

Есть код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a, b, k;
a = 67865;
b = 67864;
cout.precision(8);
for (int i = a, j = b; i < a + 100, j < b + 100; i++, j++)
{
cout << fixed << (double) i / j << endl;
k++;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

В том, что вывелось на экран нужно убрать **1.0000** в каждой строке, как это сделать не знаю.. Помогите (Должны получиться числа 4х значные)

Comment: Поясните что именно хотите получить. Числа в диапазоне `1473-1471`, что ли? Тогда просто вычтите из результата `i / j` единицу и умножьте его на 100,000,000. Дробную часть отбросьте (`cout.precision(0)`?) и получите что хотите. Но при чём тут C++, это ж арифметика для начальной школы. Или может я чего не так понял?

Comment: Ну а можно как-то без делений и умножений, тупо в начале каждой строки 6 символов удалять?

Comment: Попробуйте тогда не в int,а в string.

Comment: Простите, как?)) Можете показать?

Comment: Ничего не  понятно. Напишите, что выводится реально, и что вы хотели бы получить.

Comment: Не все понял. 67865 не уложится в int. Переменная к - не инициализирована, и, тем не менее, к++. Все-таки, тщательнЕе надо бы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, k;
    a = 67865;
    b = 67864;

    for (int i = a, j = b; i < a + 100, j < b + 100; i++, j++)
    {
        ostringstream out;
        out.precision(9);
        out << (double) i / j;
        cout << out.str().substr(6) << endl;
        k++;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да! Это мне и нужно было!